# Remove admin menu links for multiple users by email

Tags: users, array

I've got 3 admin users and would like to modify admin menu for 2 of them by their email address, not by role (since the capabilities are all the same).

This works with a single email address:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_admin_menu_links');
function remove_admin_menu_links(){
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if( $user && isset($user->user_email) && 'user@domain.com' == $user->user_email ) {
        remove_menu_page('tools.php');
        remove_menu_page('themes.php');
        remove_menu_page('options-general.php');
        remove_menu_page('plugins.php');
    }
}
```

What's the proper syntax for listing an array of email addresses?

I've tried the option below. It does nothing at all, stops working but no error either.

`if( $user && isset($user->user_email) && (in__array('user1@domain.com','user2@domain.com')) == $user->user_email ) {`

Comment: the function `in_array` is with 1 underscore and works like that : http://php.net/in_array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct usage:

```
$arr = array('user1@domain.com','user2@domain.com');
in_array($user->user_email, $arr)
```